# CMake Error: fatal error: openssl/core_names.h: No such file or directory

Tags: cmake, openssl

I have cmake project which uses openssl for TLS, I have installed openssl into my system with

> yum install openssl-devel

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
if (OPENSSL_FOUND)
message(STATUS "Found OpenSSL ${OPENSSL_VERSION}")
else()
message(STATUS "OpenSSL Not Found")
endif()
```

I got following message:

> -- Found OpenSSL 1.0.2s

However, I got following error when I include openssl header file in my project

> fatal error: openssl/core_names.h: No such file or directory

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please, include into the question post the relevant CMake code where you **link** with OpenSSL libraries (`find_package` just locates these libraries) and **complete** error message, which should note the file, which causes the given error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you might forget to add the following in your `CMakeLists.txt`

```
target_link_libraries(your_executable
    PRIVATE
        openssl
```

It does populate `include directories` of your target with path to include folder of `openssl` library, so the header can be found. You can check if this is your problem by adding

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

this will generate `compile_commands.json` file into your build folder, which contains build commands - please check if include folder of openssl library is passed as `-I` argument to your compiler (I assume you are using GCC, so -I argument passes include search paths

Comment: it worked after link library. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

This header seems to be added in OpenSSL 3, according to [this man](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/openssl-core_names.h.html).

Searching for the file in the OpenSSL 1.0.2s tree yields nothing.